# Склонировал репку, пишет мол нету необходимых файлов

Tags: github

Репозиторий успешно клонировался. Все файлы в порядке. Как начинаю запускать любой проект, в терминале появляются слова, что нет необходимых файлов. Я имею в виду в общем. Вот как вы запускаете чужой проект из гитхаба? Я к примеру нашел очень популярный блог на django, клонировал его, и начинаю прописывать запуск сервера и сразу появляются ошибки. Я в пустой папке все это дело клонирую. Что не так?

Comment: Обычно после клонирования нужно ещё запустить сборку. Конкретные команды зависят от языка на котором проект написан и часто указываются в документации к проекту.

Comment: Понял спасибо. Этот проект на джанго, но ничего не написано как запускать. Может вы знаете как запустить эту самую сборку?

Comment: После клонирования репозитория вам необходимо установить зависимости для работы с проектом, в вашем случае поможет это: [Установка зависимостей для проекта Python (Django)](https://coderoad.ru/44969794)